# How can I count/Show the number of online users in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to show the online users of my wordpress blog. Actually I want to put a sidebar widget code for my blog where a user can see that how many other users are currently online...

Comment: Are you using a plugin? if so. which one?

Comment: No I don't want to use any plugin

Comment: It's the easiest way..

Answer (score 3):

I found a good class for showing online users (count or users list). It provides two shortcodes for showing data on your website:

- online:list
- online:qty

You can easily add more functionality to it.

- [Display online Users on WordPress](http://bordoni.me/blog/2014/10/29/display-online-users-wordpress/)
- [Github repo](https://github.com/bordoni/online-now/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `QuickCount` for this operation

http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-count/

`WP-UserOnline` is good too

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-useronline/installation/

Answer (score 0):

download this plugin and activate it

https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-useronline

also try this

http://wordpress.org/plugins/awebsome-online-registered-users-widget/

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for this - GO to http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-count/ , download and install plugin on your website. Activate the plugin and you are DONE !!

It will give you complete information in ADMIN area about visitors those are online. Moreover, you can add **WIDGET in SIDEBAR** as well that shows number of online users.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use Quick Count wordpress Plugin

http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-count/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin, it has both shortcode and widgets for easy display. https://wordpress.org/plugins/cbxuseronline/

Answer (score -1):

You can try this **WP Online Active Users** plugin, Here you can easily see who is currently online Active users (logged) Status in to your WordPress admin dashboard and Provides Shortcode to display the how many users are currently online active in custom locations..

Visit: https://wordpress.org/plugins/online-active-users

Comment: This same answer as already been provided three other times to this same question.